# Theme for Civicrm / WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, css, theme

Old question I am aware. Any new answers?

Latest WordPress and CiviCRM installed.
So I'm reading that picking a theme that is mostly CSS and little JS is the way to go with compatibility in mind for CiviCRM. Any rising stars out there?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know whether it is a rising star or not, but we have had consistently good results with [Spacious](https://wordpress.org/themes/spacious/).